# Selecting from one table that does not exist on another table

Tags: sql

How can I select user 3, 4, 5 from table1 based on the condition that their number is NOT 100 on table2?

```
**table1                        table2**
id    name                    id     number
1     user1                   1      100
2     user2                   2      100
3     user3                   3      200
4     user4                   4      200
5     user5                   1      300
                              2      300
```

Comment: `select t1.id, t1.name from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id where t2.number <> 100`

Comment: `select t1.name from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id where t2.number != 100`, also, @Riad is correct.

Comment: Your title is misleading: the row/value exists in the other table but you want it to not to "exist equal to some number.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my table. It can contain many records for each id. I just want to identify the ids and names of the users that doesn't have the number of 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select name,id from table1 where id not in 
(select id from table2 where number=100)
```

Comment: For example id = 1 has both 100 and 300 in table2. Your query will return from table1 where id = 1.

Comment: But user5 wouldn't be included, right? How will I do that?

Comment: Will work fine as long as there are no NULL's returned from the sub-query. (If there are, no data at all will be returned. That's why I always encourage `NOT EXISTS` instead!

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to verify that the same id doesn't have a number 100 in table2.

```
select *
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2
                  where t2.number = 100
                    and t2.id = t1.id)
```